# Behavior of WPF/c# applications

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying the browser applications with WPF and do not understand a thing. An .exe file and a .XBAP file is generated from Visual Studio Ide. If I start the XBAP files regularly play in the browser, if I start the exe file, nothing happens. I think that the .exe file is the same application XBAP in executable format, is not it?
Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Do you need any specific command like arguments?

Comment: No, it's a simple page with no parameters. Thank you.